# python 3.6.1 format print unicode

Tags: python

why so in python 3.6.1 with simple code like:

```
print(f'\xe4')
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    print(f'\xe4')
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <lambda>
    print = lambda text, end='\n', file=sys.stdout: print(text, end=end, file=file)
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <lambda>
    print = lambda text, end='\n', file=sys.stdout: print(text, end=end, file=file)
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <lambda>
    print = lambda text, end='\n', file=sys.stdout: print(text, end=end, file=file)
  [Previous line repeated 990 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Might be a bug in Python 3.6.1. Works fine for me in Python 3.6.7.

Comment: I'm not surprised if you've overriden the builtin print with `print = lambda text, end='\n', file=sys.stdout: print(text, end=end, file=file)`... You've shadowed print with a lambda, then inside it calling print, which calls print, which calls print... and then *boom*

Comment: Please provide more context so that the problem can be reproduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So let's recap: you have overridden the built-in `print` function with this:

```
print = lambda text, end='\n', file=sys.stdout: print(text, end=end, file=file)
```

Which is the same as

```
def print(text, end='\n', file=sys.stdout):
    print(text, end=end, file=file)
```

As you can see, this function calls itself recursively, but there is no recursion base, no condition when it finishes. You end up with a classic example of infinite recursion.

This has absolutely nothing to do with Unicode or formatting. Simply do not name your functions after builtins:

```
def my_print(text, end='\n', file=sys.stdout):
    print(text, end=end, file=file)

my_print('abc')  # works
```

Or at least keep the reference to the original:

```
print_ = print

def print(text, end='\n', file=sys.stdout):
    print_(text, end=end, file=file)

print('abc')  # works as well
```

Note: if the function is already overwritten, you will have to run `del print` (or restart the interpreter) to get back the original builtin.

Comment: Almost looks like the OP is trying to write the equivalent of `my_print = functools.partial(print, end=\n', file=sys.stdout)` or similar...

Comment: You don't have to restart the interpreter... you can just use `del print` to remove the `lambda`'d version and then `print` the builtin one will pop back... eg... `print = 5`... `print`... (integer 5) - `del print`, `print`: (<function print>
)

Comment: @JonClements Partial is a bit different because you lose the ability to supply a non-default argument, although I'm not sure if this is very useful in this case anyway. I'll add the `del` hint, thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with partial? It just fixes some arguments which the OP seems to be doing but otherwise, it's callable exactly the same as the original...

Comment: @JonClements With the one that overwrites `print` you can use the new default most of the time, but specify for example `print(123, end=', ')` when you need something different, using the same function. The original intent is not very clear (\n and stdout *are* the defaults), so I don't know what OP is really trying to do here.

Comment: Yeah... wasn't suggesting to shadow print using partial - just that it's a bit more obvious, easier syntax as to what you're doing (eg - fixing arguments) - certainly wouldn't bind it back to print to break things later :) Good explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Works for me as well. But maybe it'll work for you with:

```
print(chr(0xe4))
```

Comment: It works fine... the OP has created a new function called `print` which calls `print`... hence the recursion... Nothing wrong with what the OPs doing otherwise :)